# How to pass command line arguments to bash script when executing with at?

Tags: shell-script, scheduling, at

I have a bash script needs run at a specific time and found out `at` is pretty much does what I need to do. But the problem is I'm not sure how can I pass command line arguments to the bash script through `at`. Below command is what I finally ended up after looking through some other solutions.

```
echo "-f job.sh argument" | xargs at now + 2 minutes
```

But this does not work. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `xargs` (and `-f`). `at` reads command from standard input if you don't use `-f`.

From [the POSIX specification for `at`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/at.html):

> The `at` utility shall read commands from standard input and group them together as an at-job, to be executed at a later time.

In your case:

```
echo 'job.sh argument' | at now + 2 minutes
```

This would execute `job.sh argument` in two minutes.

Alternatively,

```
at now + 2 minutes <<'AT_JOB'
job.sh argument
AT_JOB
```

You can't pass arguments to an `at` job really (`at -f job.sh argument ...` would not work), so you must make the arguments part of the job, which both of the above variations do.

Comment: The OP is still missing some sort of command though

Comment: @roaima I just spotted that. I think they want to pass the `-f` as if calling `at` with a file.

Comment: @Kusalananda I tested the command `echo 'job.sh argument' | at now + 2 minutes` before I posting this question, and though I get the warning I usually get when I execute script through `at`, the script never executes. And also it shows the time when the job gets executed (in this case 2 minutes after the current time)

Answer (score 0):

```
at now + 2 minutes
/your/script -flags parameters
^D
```

where I've written `^D` you should use <kbd>Ctrl D</kbd>

Or programmatically,

```
echo '/your/script -flags parameters' |  at now + 2 minutes
```

Example

```
date
Fri 24 Jan 12:45:18 GMT 2020

echo 'date >test.txt' | at now + 2 minutes
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 1173 at Fri Jan 24 12:47:00 2020
```

Comment: hello @roaima unfortunately the last option doesn't execute my script in the given time

Comment: I think there must be something else happening then. Please see example in my (updated) answer.